# Angular 2, Typescript Module has no exported constant 'FORM_DIRECTIVES'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

I am trying to include one existing component in my app and from sample code I have these dependencies:

```
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgClass} from 'angular2/common';
```

Now I am using `'@angular'` instead of `'angular2'` which would I think be something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, CORE_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/core';
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/forms';
```

However I get this error

```
mypath/node_modules/@angular/forms/index"' has no exported member 'FORM_DIRECTIVES'.
mypath/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'CORE_DIRECTIVES'.
```

How am I supposed to include `FORM_DIRECTIVES` and if they are no longer part of `angular2` what is the replacement or new way to resolve dependencies?

I have checked angular [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc0-2016-05-02) but couldn't find anything

Answer (score 8):

`FORM_DIRECTIVES` are now part of `FormsModule`, so you should import `FormsModule` and add it to your module's imports.

`CORE_DIRECTIVES` are now part of `CommonModule` which is exported by `BrowserModule`. You already import `BrowserModule` in your `AppModule`, so you don't need to do anything about `CORE_DIRECTIVES`. Here's the example of basic module with imported `FormsModule`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: what about CORE_DIRECTIVES or other? where can I find list of these changes?

Comment: @DarkoRodic Edited my answer, added part about `CORE_DIRECTIVES`. I don't know where you can find complete list of changes to be honest, maybe someone else can help you with that.

Answer (score 2):

you should to install :

```
npm install --save angular2
```

like that :

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@ngrx/store": "^1.2.1",
    "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15"
  }
```

This works:

```
import {ControlGroup, Control, FORM_DIRECTIVES} from "angular2/common";

@Component({
    selector: 'person-form',
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
    template: require('./person_form.html')
})

export class PersonForm { ... } 
This fails with FORM_DIRECTIVES as undefined:

import {ControlGroup, Control} from "angular2/common";

@Component({
    selector: 'person-form',
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
    template: require('./person_form.html')
})

export class PersonForm { ... }
```